# JAVA - Find out how long until an event

Tags: java

I can't find a way too properly find how long the player has left.

The idea is they claim a reward, and then must wait 24 hours, here is my code:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage("You still have " + Misc.msToString(player.getLastDiscordDaily() - System.currentTimeMillis()) + " until you can claim your reward.").queue();
```

player.getLastDiscordDaily() is saved as System.currentTimeMillis()

time used too convert time:

```
 public static String msToString(long ms) {
        long totalSecs = ms/1000;
        long hours = (totalSecs / 3600);
        long mins = (totalSecs / 60) % 60;
        long secs = totalSecs % 60;
        String minsString = (mins == 0)
                ? "00"
                : ((mins < 10)
                ? "0" + mins
                : "" + mins);
        String secsString = (secs == 0)
                ? "00"
                : ((secs < 10)
                ? "0" + secs
                : "" + secs);
        if (hours > 0)
            return hours + " hours, " + minsString + " minutes and " + secsString;
        else if (mins > 0)
            return mins + " minutes and " + secsString + "seconds.";
        else return ":" + secsString;
    }
```

Output:

You still have :0-3 until you can claim your reward.

Excepted output:

You still have X hours, X minutes and X seconds until you can claim your reward.

Comment: So shouldn't you be adding 24 hours (in ms) onto `player.getLastDiscordDaily()` before you subtract the current time?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Simply changed the first line of code too the following:

```
 event.getChannel().sendMessage("You still have " + Misc.msToString((player.getLastDiscordDaily() + 86400000) - System.currentTimeMillis()) + " until you can claim your reward.").queue();
```